# Cannot Xcode Export Adhoch Archive

Tags: ios, xcode

If I run an Xcode build, then export that archive from within Xcode, it works.

If I take the same export options used by that export, and then manually run the following:

`xcodebuild -verbose -exportArchive -archivePath build/MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath build -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist | xcpretty`

Then it fails with the following error:

`AppThinning.StubError(errorDescription: Optional("ipatool failed"))`

I can't see a clear error reason in the detailed logs. There are some warnings, but its not clear if they are the root cause, since it keeps going up until the end, where the above message appears.

How can I troubleshoot this?

The export options are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.foo.myapp</key>
        <string>[redacted]</string>
        <key>com.foo.myapp.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension</key>
        <string>[redacted]</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>Apple Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>[redacted]</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Edit:** Note that the setting for thinning really is correct, as per documentation, and what Xcode (via GUI) uses itself, successfully. (Yeah, Xcode, right?)

Comment: Can you explain `<string>&lt;none&gt;</string>`? That looks like it might be the problem.

Comment: @matt I should have mentioned this. This is actual correct setting, as per documentation, and what Xcode Archive (via GUI) uses itself.  (Was pretty surprised myself!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, buried in the logs.

So the answer to the question above is:

- Carefully review each of the log output files.

The problem: I was running a Ruby under RVM and some dependencies were fighting. Dropping back to the raw Apple Ruby worked. (Presumably, installing the correct dependencies also could have).

Comment: Thank you, I have been fighting with this error for almost a month and finally found out from you that rvm is the root cause. Switching back to Apple's System ruby resolved this issue :)

Comment: Good job, glad you finally found it.

Comment: How to switch to apple's System ruby?

Comment: @KushalDesai Make sure it is in the path before another Ruby like one provided by Ruby Version Manager (RVM) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75179578/11810933), switch to Apple's System Ruby. This can be done by simply executing `rvm use system` in the terminal

This operation only affects the current session, and of course, assumes you have RVM installed.

Comment: chruby system if you using chruby